# How to keep the last value in Pandas without removing the rows

Tags: pandas

I am working on a dataset in which I want to attribute the last action of a user to a certain goal. In the process I arrive at below tableset.

```
table

date         |  action_id   |  u_id       | goal   
2016-01-08   |  CUID22      |   586758    |  'Goal#1'
2017-03-04   |  CUID45      |   586758    |  'Goal#1'
2018-09-01   |  CUID30      |   586758    |  'Goal#1'
```

How can I remove/replace the first two u_id or goal values whilst keeping the rows to arrive at below tableset.

```
table

date         |  action_id   |  u_id       | goal   
2016-01-08   |  CUID22      |   NaN       |  NaN
2017-03-04   |  CUID45      |   NaN       |  NaN
2018-09-01   |  CUID30      |   586758    |  'Goal#1'
```

Comment: Can you add more sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Thank you jezrael for your response. I made some changes. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: I add answer, how working with your all data?

Comment: It seems to work great. The stats of the end result makes sense. Very grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you need [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
cols = ['u_id','goal']
df.loc[df.duplicated(cols, keep='last'), cols] = np.nan
```

Or:

```
cols = ['u_id','goal']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df.duplicated(cols, keep='last'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   date  action_id  u_id  goal
0  2016          0   NaN   NaN
1  2017          1   NaN   NaN
2  2018          2   1.0   1.0
```